# The usage of the word "loose" in "the bun of hair loose on her neck"

Tags: word-usage

> She looked down at me, the bun of hair loose on her neck.

The above sentence is taken from *Dreams Do Come True* by Jim Bishop.

Is the word **loose** used correctly?

Comment: Why do you think it is not correct? It sounds fine to me. If you can [edit] your question to be more specific, that would help.

Comment: Please do not use pairs of angled single quotes for typographic quotes, as this is awkward to read and usually messes up formatting; just use ordinary double quotes (`"`) or full-on Unicode (`“”`).

Comment: What does your dictionary say  about " loose"?

Answer (score 1):

The writer is expressing that woman's gesture.

[Bun](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=bun) is a hairstyle with hair put into a tight roll. But here, it's *loose* on her neck.

Comment: +1. Here, "loose" means that it was not tightly rolled. The hair may have been loosely rolled up to begin with, or it may have worked itself loose.

Answer (score 0):

I think **loose** it's used correctly.

I think what you might be expecting are more modern or more typical patterns people might use. Like any of the following:

- Her bun of hair hung loosely upon her neck.
- Her bun of hair was loose upon her neck.

Which are both also correct.